# List calendars enabled for Android Wear

Tags: calendar, wear-os

I want to list the calendars enabled for Android Wear syncing in the Android Wear app's Calendar settings.
Any way to do this?
The WearableCalendarContract available on the wearable does only lists instances. The regular CalendarContract on the phone does not provide that information.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know you can create a [`DataItem`](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/wearable/DataItem) to provide data automatic syncing between the handheld and wearable and extend `WearableListenerService (for services)` lets you listen for important data layer events in a service, bind service when it needs to send data items or messages.

Sync your data manually, fetch it from the provider and send it to the `wearable` via `DataItem API`. For more information about syncing data between handheld and wearable check this document: https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/data-layer/index.html

Comment: Its possible to disable certain calendars in the Android Wear app. I wan't to honour those settings but I can't find a wait to access that specific information.